# Parallel Read and write application in java

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I am developing an application in java where i am using a shared LinkedBlocking Queue and i am creating multiple threads for reading and writing it. I have created the code as below but i am unable to get the desired result.

For result i am using a shared file which is being written  by both the threads (read and write one).

Please tell me whats wrong in my code:

Message Reader.java

```
package com.aohandling.messagereader;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.aohandling.messagequeue.MessageQueue;

public class MessageReader implements Runnable
{
    public static BufferedWriter out;

    public static void init()
    {
    file = new File("AOHandle.txt");
    try
    {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        System.out.println("Init ");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    static File file = null;

    public void run()
    {
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
        String s = MessageQueue.getMessageQueue().poll();
        if (s != null)
        {
            out.write("queue - " + MessageQueue.getMessageQueue().poll() + "---"  + ft.format(new Date()) + "\n");
        }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

MessageWriter.java

```
package com.aohandling.writer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.aohandling.messagequeue.MessageQueue;
import com.aohandling.messagereader.MessageReader;

public class MessageWriter implements Runnable
{

    int n;
    private int messageSequence;

    public MessageWriter(int messageSequence)
    {
    this.messageSequence = messageSequence;
    }

    public void run()
    {

    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
        MessageReader.out.append("Writing----AO - " + this.messageSequence + "-----" + ft.format(new Date()) + "\n");
        MessageQueue.getMessageQueue().put("AO " + this.messageSequence);
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

MessageQueue.java

```
package com.aohandling.messagequeue;

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class MessageQueue {

    private static LinkedBlockingQueue<String> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    public static LinkedBlockingQueue<String> getMessageQueue() {
        return MessageQueue.messageQueue;
    }

    public static void setMessageQueue(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> messageQueue) {
        MessageQueue.messageQueue = messageQueue;
    }
}
```

TestAOHandlingRead.java

```
package com.aohandling.main;

import com.aohandling.messagereader.MessageReader;
import com.aohandling.writer.MessageWriter;

public class TestAOHandlingRead
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    MessageReader.init();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
    {
        Thread readThread = new Thread(new MessageReader());
        readThread.start();
    }
    write();

    }
    public static void write()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        Thread writeThread = new Thread(new MessageWriter(i));
        writeThread.start();

    }
    }
}
```

TestAOHandlingWrite.java

```
package com.aohandling.main;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import com.aohandling.writer.MessageWriter;

public class TestAOHandlingWrite {

    int count = 0;

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      MessageWriter.init();
        for (int i=0; i<= 20; i++) {
         if (i%2 ==0) {
             try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

         Thread writeThread = new Thread(new MessageWriter(i));
            writeThread.start();

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the desired result? What went wrong?

Comment: desired result is that i want to see parallel read and write operations in txt file which is being written by two threads.

What is going wrong is that how to run this application from single main and also writer thread is not able to write the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you will use a FileChannel, since File channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. In addition I refactored your code, the channel to your file will be created once, during the the first load of MessageReader class by the class loader.

```
public class MessageReader implements Runnable {
    private static FileChannel channel;

    static {
    try {
        System.out.println("Init ");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                "AOHandle.txt", true);

        FileChannel channel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
        System.out.println("Init ");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

        public void run() {
    while (true) {
        FileLock fileLock = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
            String s = MessageQueue.getMessageQueue().poll();
            if (s != null) {
                String message = "queue - "
                        + MessageQueue.getMessageQueue().poll() + "---"
                        + ft.format(new Date()) + "\n";
                fileLock = channel.lock();
                channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes()));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileLock != null) {
                    fileLock.release();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The best practice is to open a channel to a file in one place and share him between your threads, since in your code no one closes the file.